# Using Redis in an untrusted environment (multiple users)

Tags: redis

I've been doing some research into Redis and the security model. My issue is that I will have numerous users using Redis as a caching layer, each for their own applications. I'm in a shared environment in which I cannot split users into their own VPSes or instances.

Each user IS however chrooted to their own home directories and spawn their own processes. Would it be possible to run Redis-Server under each user account so they have their own instance and if so, how?

Comment: Redis has no such functionality. It was [not designed for it](http://redis.io/topics/security). Each user would need their own Redis instance, _and_ some way to isolate them from other users.

Comment: Damn, at the least I was looking per database authentication..

Answer (score 1):

Redis 6 is currently in beta and will probably be released soon. It provides support for multiple accounts and access control lists, so you can share one Redis instances with many users.

The ACL documentation is available at https://redis.io/topics/acl

Comment: Redis 6 is released (ACL is onboard).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run multiple instances of Redis on the same server, each using a separate config file with a separate:

- Password
- PID file
- Port
- Log File
- Directory

An example of such can be found here:

http://chrislaskey.com/blog/342/running-multiple-redis-instances-on-the-same-server/

Answer (score 0):

you can user multiple '**prefix**' in connection configure

```
let client = redis.createClient({
          host,
          port,
          user,
          password,
          prefix,
});
```

source : [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)